# Programming an SK6812 LED - it's always white

Tags: microcontroller, led

I'm trying to program an SK6812 LED. I've finally gotten it to light up at all, but it's just solid white.

I'm programming in rust and the microcontroller is a rp2040. I'm using https://github.com/rp-rs/rp-hal for interfacing with the hardware.

Here are the pieces of code that I think are relevant:

```rust
let mut delay = |ns: u32| {
    let syst = &mut core.SYST;
    const MAX_TICKS: u32 = 0x00ffffff;
    syst.set_clock_source(SystClkSource::Core);

    let ticks = (ns as u64 * clocks.system_clock.freq().to_Hz() as u64) / 1_000_000_000;

    // As the register only accepts numbers up to 0x00ffffff (24 bits), it's
    // likely we may need to do one or multiple "full count down cycle",
    // followed by an additional, "precise" one.
    let full_cycles = ticks >> 24;
    for _ in 0..full_cycles {
        syst.set_reload(MAX_TICKS);
        syst.clear_current();
        syst.enable_counter();

        while !syst.has_wrapped() {}
    }

    let precision_ticks = ticks as u32 & MAX_TICKS;

    if precision_ticks == 0 {
        return;
    }

    syst.set_reload(precision_ticks - 1);
    syst.clear_current();
    syst.enable_counter();

    while !syst.has_wrapped() {}

    syst.disable_counter();
};

let mut pin = pins.gpio26.into_push_pull_output();

let mut send_bit = |delay: &mut dyn FnMut(u32), bit: u8| {
    if bit == 1 {
        pin.set_high().unwrap();
        delay(900);
        pin.set_low().unwrap();
        delay(600);
    } else {
        pin.set_high().unwrap();
        delay(400);
        pin.set_low().unwrap();
        delay(900);
    }
};

let mut send_byte = |delay: &mut dyn FnMut(u32), byte: u8| {
    for i in (0..8).rev() {
        send_bit(delay, (byte >> i) & 1);
    }
};

loop {
    send_byte(&mut delay, 0);
    send_byte(&mut delay, 1);
    send_byte(&mut delay, 0);
    delay(500_000_000);

    send_byte(&mut delay, 1);
    send_byte(&mut delay, 0);
    send_byte(&mut delay, 0);
    delay(500_000_000);

    send_byte(&mut delay, 0);
    send_byte(&mut delay, 0);
    send_byte(&mut delay, 1);
    delay(500_000_000);
}
```

I need a custom `delay` function because, as far as I'm concerned, the LEDs require timings in the nanoseconds range, and the HAL provided delay only goes down to microseconds. Chances are high that there is some issue in `delay`. *Sometimes the LED is briefly green before turning white... which might be another hint that it is timing related?*

This is my first time doing anything ***this*** close to the hardware, so please bear with me, and if you need additional information, I would appreciate if you told me where to find it, if not obvious. Thanks! :)

Oh, and I sadly don't have an oscilloscope to look at the actual values on the wires... Hope I can fix this without having to buy one...

I'm also not sure if this might belong on Stock Overflow... but, at least to me, it seems quite specific to microcontrollers, and single bits on the wires, but feel free to tell me if that's the case, or move it (if possible).

Comment: the bit timing is wrong ... check the SK6812 datasheet

Comment: @jsotola I referenced the following arduino code when writing my implementation, it uses those timings: https://github.com/bigjosh/SimpleNeoPixelDemo/blob/master/SimpleNeopixelDemo/SimpleNeopixelDemo.ino. That code was able to drive my LEDs, but I will try it with the timings specified in the datasheet.

Comment: @jsotola I changed the timings (same order as mentioned in the question) to 600 T1H, 600 T1L, 300 T0H, 900 H0L. Are those the timings you had in mind? Sadly, the LED is still white.

Comment: the SimpleNeoPixelDemo shows timing for the WS2812 ... maybe that is what you have

Comment: check the timing in your program ... use regular LED, your board may have one built in ... edit the `send_bit` function timing to 10 seconds ON, 1 second OFF,  for both parts of the `if bit == 1 {` block .... use a stopwatch to confirm 10 second delay ... do 100 second delay for greater precision

Comment: @jsotola I'm not sure. I bought these: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003636607308.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.5.72061802hj7nNX. But I've read that those sort of LEDs are compatible with "neopixels", and they do work with the adafruit library on the Arduino platform. I measured the timings, and they were within .2 seconds of 10s. But of course, I have no way to measure much more granular than that by hand.

Comment: I could hook up a second microcontroller to measure if the 10s delay is correct, but I don't think I can measure down to nanoseconds...

Comment: I don't think there's going to be any way to debug this without at least some sort of analysis tool. Luckily for you this is well within the capabilities of cheap tools like a [BitMagic](https://1bitsquared.com/products/bitmagic-basic) logic analyser or a Hantek 6022BE oscilloscope.

Comment: @Polynomial wouldn't the sampling rate of the tool you linked be way too slow? To measure down to 100ns, one would need a rate of at least 100Mhz, no? But I guess I'm going to look into getting some sort of oscilloscope. In the meantime, if anybody spots something wrong with me code, please tell me :)

Comment: @Elias 24MHz gets you one sample every 41.6ns. Should be fine.

Comment: @Polynomial, ah I had my maths wrong... but in that case, couldn't I hook up a second rp2040 and use that to measure?

Comment: @Elias You could, if you're confident that you can write working code to do so, with precise timing so that your measurements are correct. But the benefit of having a proper dedicated measurement tool is that it takes your own mistakes out of the picture.

Comment: `I have no way to measure much more granular than that by hand` ... yes you do ... do a 100 second interval ... or a 1000 second interval

Comment: you could also send data to a serial port and use a computer to record the time interval ... Treaters has logging with timestamps ... Arduino IDE serial monitor also has a timestamp option